# How to Create or Enable Person Account in developer Edition

Tags: person-accounts

I want to create or Enable Person Account in Developer Edition , I followed Implementing person Accounts Pdf, but it not possible to do that , Can you anyone give some guideliness

Regrads ,

Ganesh

Comment: Have you requested salesforce to enable this in your developer org?

Comment: Thanks for your Reply @MohithKumar Where ill request to salesforce , using Email or contact support...

Comment: Create a simple case with your developer account and mention the reason as education and training .Also i have answered below as that was the first resolution and check why the issue happened

Comment: Potential duplicate of [How to enable person account in free developer edition?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/27420/102)

Answer (score 3):

To Enable person Account is salesforce ,first and foremost thing is to contact salesforce support and get it enabled

The next step will be as per implementation guide

Comment: Be aware that once the person accounts are turned on in an org they can not be turned off.

Comment: Actually, the first step is NOT to contact SF Support; you must first setup a "Business Account"-style Record Type on the Account and then you can contact them. You must have at least one Record Type defined on Accounts.

Answer (score 1):

After Summer 22 Release, we can enable person account from the setup and don't need to raise a case with Salesforce Support.

Once enabled this feature cannot be disabled.

For more details refer below:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_person_enable.htm&type=5