# How to enable person account in free developer edition? I am not seeing a link to submit case

Tags: person-accounts

How to enable person account in free developer edition? I am not seeing a link to submit or create a case in free developer edition. Any ideas.

**Update: 
Once i click Open a case, it takes me to login screen. once i logged in i got this page and did not see a page to submit a case.**

**Updated on 11-Feb-2014**

Exact Scenario of the issue which i am facing now...Now, can anyone suggest what else i need to do?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The fact that there is a login link & icon at the top right of your screenshot indicates that you are not logged in when this shot was taken. Have you tried navigating to Help & Training while logged in to your Dev Org as Sdry shows below? Log out of all other orgs while doing this to keep the sessions clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to contact salesforce to enable person accounts.

You should be able to log support cases from a free developer org too. (I can do it on any of mine). Do expect a few days of waiting for free support. If you have access to higher degree's of support in other orgs, it's worth logging the case there, but do mention for what org id you are requesting this to be enabled.

[image: Normal org]
[image: Community enabled org]
[image: Contact Support]

Then you should get this:
[image: Log a Case]

Comment: i did not get a page to submit a case. i have updated my question above. Please have a look on it. What else i can do?

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in ? You do not appear logged in on the screenshot you posted. Once I login I see the case option after clicking "contact support".

Comment: yes, i did. i logged in, after that i saw the screen above.

Comment: i am seeing Help & Training in your screen but in my login i am seeing only Help. Any ideas?

Comment: No I don't know why you have a different interface than I do in my developer org. Help(&training) > Contact Support > Open a Case is there in all my developer orgs, i just checked.

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are a Partner, you can submit a case through the partner portal and specify the Org Id. If you're not a partner, and have access to an org with access to Support, then you could try that. But I would be a lot more nervous in that case that Support would enable it for the org from which your case originates, rather than your Dev org.

If you're an independent developer on the platform, it's not difficult to [join the Salesforce Partners program](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/join/) and get access to the Partner Portal, from which you could log such a case. If you work for a firm that is already a partner, you'll need to inquire internally about getting access to the Partner Portal.

Answer (score 1):

After Summer 22 Release, we can enable person account from the setup and don't need to raise a case with Salesforce Support.

Once enabled this feature cannot be disabled.

For more details refer below:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_person_enable.htm&type=5