# How to enable Person Accounts in a Dev org.?

Tags: account, person-accounts, salesforce-support

I followed the below [Account setting feature to enable Person Account](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person_enable.htm&type=5).

[image: Enable Person Accounts in Account settings]

This seems not getting saved even though I have followed all 3 guidelines. Then found this article explaining why we [Cannot save 'Allow customer support to enable Person Accounts' setting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000267858&language=en_US&type=1)

> This is often due to a conflict in the settings of the "Authenticated
>   Website" license. If so, please note it within your case to request
>   the activation of the Person Accounts feature, grant login access to
>   Support and our Support agents will assist with the next steps.

Accordingly, I tried to create a support request from the Dev. org. but when I try to log in, it logs me out, just after log-in with no messages.

Is there a successful workaround to get Person Accounts enabled in Dev. org. please. Appreciate any thoughts, Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried in a new private browser window? I've had similar issues with support in dev org where something to do with the SSO setup just fails like that.

Comment: You can’t create a case from a dev org. They do not provide support which is why they slam the door on you. I suggest trying a scratch org where you can enable that feature when creating it IIRC

Comment: Thanks @MattLacey and Eric, Somehow managed to get to them via a Prod org. and get it done!  :)

Comment: Potential duplicate of [How to enable person account in free developer edition?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/27420/102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Summer 22 Release, we can enable person account from the setup and don't need to raise a case with Salesforce Support.

For more details refer below:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_person_enable.htm&type=5

Answer (score 3):

Seems it's not possible to do it using dev org's Salesforce username. But we were able to enable Person Accounts by creating a Case using a Production org.

Also please feel free to [vote this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cQn4QAE) for Salesforce to enable customers to signup for Person Accounts enabled Org without having to go through this process.